# Change already-written console application to project of "Windows Service" type?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have a console application which I need to change to a windows service. How do I do this? In Properties it only has "Windows Application", "Console Application" and "Class Library" in the drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, they are different enough that you need to create a new project of, you guessed it, "Windows Service" type.

You may want to refactor all of the common stuff into a new DLL so you could use it from the Windows Service and the Console Application (as a backup/test).

(Re)Installing Windows Services everytime you need to test is a real hassle, so I advice to keep your console app for testing.